# Paypal API get email by account id

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using Paypal transaction search api https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/ I receive the transactions that contain one email in the field `payer_info.email_address` (and sometimes `payer_info.account_id` that could play role later in this question)

However, on their UI in these transactions I see TWO, often different, emails:

`Contact info` and `Payment Sent to` (it's on the page `https://www.paypal.com/activity/payment/[TRANSACTIONIDHERE]`)

Now, analysing this report, I noticed that the email given in the field `payer_info.email_address` *sometimes* is `Contact info` and *sometimes* is `Payment Sent to`. I have a hunch it could somehow related to the presence of `payer_info.account_id`.

Now, the question is, what is the email the payment really was sent to? And secondary question, can I ever procure **both** emails from the transaction?

Note that I only analysed payouts so far (negative amount transactions that are the main transactions i.e. have no `paypal_reference_id` and also their code are `T0000` or `T0001` so the question is scoped by these specifics.

If it matters, I do not use Paypal rest SDK, doing a barebone REST Api request.

Comment: You are using the Transaction Search API but your question is not about its use, but rather the customer data it's returning. Contact PayPal's support and reference the specific data and customers/accounts you have questions about

Comment: Thank you Preston. The data shape and the API data contracts are the main part and the core of why we use APIs.

Comment: You are asking what the payer.email_address corresponds to in PayPal's transaction views, which is a customer data question PayPal will need to answer (with specifics to go on). From an API standpoint the only thing I can say is a method of getting "both" emails for a transaction is highly unlikely as it's not documented anywhere